# Who is user "unset" in aureport?

Tags: logs, users, audit, linux-audit

I couldn't find this elusive "unset" user in `/etc/passwd` and there is no mention of him in `man aureport` although she scored the most number of hits on my audit log:

```
# aureport -u -i --summary --start today

User Summary Report
===========================
total  auid
===========================
888  unset
222  root
55  creepy_user
```

Who is the "unset" user and what does he do for a living?

Comment: `unset` refers to the fact that 888 items are assigned no user id  ie "user id not set"

Comment: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.security.audit/542

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the definition of `auid` from this SuSE page, titled: [Understanding the Audit Logs and Generating Reports](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled10/audit_sp1/data/sec_audit_aureport.html):

> #### auid
>
> The audit ID. A process is given an audit ID on user login. This ID is then 
>   handed down to any child process started by the initial process of the user. 
>   Even if the user changes his identity (for example, becomes root), the audit 
>   ID stays the same. Thus you can always trace actions to the original user who 
>   logged in.

I would conclude that there was no login performed by a user for the process that was handed down to the child process that was started. There are ways to run processes on Unix without actually logging in.

I believe `pam_loginuid` is responsible for setting this. You can take a look at the man page for more on it.

Comment: Hmm, does it mean that an audit for a process not performed by a logged in user directly, like someone creating a cron job to perform a task, is normally untraceable with audit? Also, we have a user called `nobody` who seems to be left out :)